# Java Spring - cannot use GetMapping

Tags: spring-boot, maven, http, spring-mvc, tomcat

Initially, I generated my project via this site. I downloaded it and opened it in my IntelliJ Ultimate. I made all of the configurations however I keep getting an "HTTP Status 404" error when I try to display some text in my localhost page:

[image][image][image]

```
package com.icttech.springBootDemo.apiDemo;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ProductsController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String get() {
        return "Deneme 1";
    }

    @GetMapping("/products")
    public String get2() {
        return "Deneme 2";
    }

}
```

I have tried everything I can do but could not figure this out. I would really be appreciated if somebody helped me. out

I checked from cmd that if my HTTP is busy but nothing else using it except my IntelliJ Tomcat. I also tried building my project with this:When I opened my project as Jakarta EE, it works.

Comment: can you please share application.properties file? also your tomcat running on 8080 port?